# Не могу понять как работает алгоритм

Tags: python

Не могу разобраться в цикле `for-in`, и поэтому не понимаю весь код.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто загуглите «сортировка пузырьком» и в результатах будет куча разнообразных объяснений

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проходит по длине списка

`for i in range(len(nums)):`

так же проходит по длине списка вычетая текущее значение i и вычетая 1

`for j in range(len(nums)-i-1):`

если число списка по индексу j больше числа по индексу j + 1

`if nums[j] > nums[j+1]:`

если условие if равно, то nums[j] == nums[j+1], а nums[j+1] == nums[j] (меняются значениями)

`nums[j], nums[j+1] = nums[j+1], nums[j]`

Comment: Могу продебажить.

Comment: Прочитал код вслух с выражением ;)

Comment: Убрал лишние выделения заголовками ..

Comment: @Kromster - спасибо, а то от болда в глазах рябило